# cannot find module realm.node at node.js with realm database

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, realm, ubuntu-16.04

https://realm.io/news/realm-node-js-express-blog-tutorial/ I tried to apply the realm database to my node.js project by referring to the link here. However I got the error. my node version 6.10 , my os is Ubuntu 16.04.1, and raspberry pie 2. How can I fix this error?

```
pi@pi:~/workspace/anapp.kr$ sudo node bin/www
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/pi/workspace/anapp.kr/node_modules/realm/compiled/node-v48_linux_arm/realm.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/workspace/anapp.kr/node_modules/realm/lib/index.js:77:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
pi@pi:~/workspace/anapp.kr$ node -v
v6.10.0
pi@pi:~/workspace/anapp.kr$ npm -v
3.10.10
pi@pi:~/workspace/anapp.kr$
```

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs-legacy` this will re-install node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

realm-js doesn't support Linux ARM out of the box.

That's because the database engine itself doesn't have a Raspberry Pi-compatible binary distribution, but it's open source so you can try building it yourself.

Clone one of the tags - 2.3.0 for example, on https://github.com/realm/realm-core on your Pi and follow the build instructions in the readme (but instead run `sh build.sh build-node`). If it builds successfully export an environment variable called `REALM_CORE_PREFIX` pointing to the absolute path of your realm-core checkout and reinstall the realm module from npm.